# Из-за чего массив в переменной меняется с определенного момента?

Tags: php, api, циклы, переменные

Уважаемые эксперты!

Разбираю хардкод, бьюсь и не могу понять один момент. Вначале кода результаты условий складываются в массив $history_fns. Если внутри первых двух foreach выводить (вардампом) $history_fns, то данные появляются в правильном порядке. Во второй части кода (ниже черты) вывод $history_fns приводит уже к другим результатам - данные следуют в обратном порядке. Почему это происходит? Вторая часть кода отвечает за вывод информации "на фронт", из-за пертурбаций с $history_fns она представляется в неправильном порядке..

```
$history_fns = [];
$xq = 0;
/* $history_fns['Совладельцы'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq] */
                          
foreach ($history_egrul[data] as $key => $value) { 
                                  foreach ($value[changes] as $key1=> $value1) {
                           if($value1[title][value]=='uchr_dol' || $value1[title][value]=='uchr') {
                               $history_fns['Совладельцы'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq] = $value1[val_old];
                                $history_fns['Совладельцы'][$value1[grn_date]][add][$xq] = $value1[val_new];
                               
                         }
                                      
                                 if($value1[title][value]=='ruk') {
                           $history_fns['Руководитель'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq] = $value1[val_old];
                                /* var_dump($history_fns['Руководитель'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq]); */
                            $history_fns['Руководитель'][$value1[grn_date]][add][$xq] = $value1[val_new];
                                     
                         }

                                  if($value1[title][value]=='addr') {
                           $history_fns['Адрес'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq] = $value1[val_old];   
                            $history_fns['Адрес'][$value1[grn_date]][add][$xq] = $value1[val_new];
                                      
                         }
                        
                         if($value1[title][value]=='okved') {
                           $history_fns['Основной вид деятельности'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq] = $value1[val_old];   
                            $history_fns['Основной вид деятельности'][$value1[grn_date]][add][$xq] = $value1[val_new];
                             
                         }
                     
                                   if($value1[title][value]=='uchr_inn') {
                           $history_fns['ИНН совладельцев'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq] = $value1[val_old];   
                            $history_fns['ИНН совладельцев'][$value1[grn_date]][add][$xq] = $value1[val_new];
                                      
                         }
                         
                                   if($value1[title][value]=='Usumma') {
                          if($value1[val_old][0][value]!=0) {$history_fns['Доля организации'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq] = $value1[val_old];   }
                           if($value1[val_new][0][value]!=0) { $history_fns['Доля организации'][$value1[grn_date]][add][$xq] = $value1[val_new];   }
                         }
                         
                         $xq++;
                     //   echo "<br><br>";
                                      
                     }
            
                      
                  } // print_r($history_egrul);
```

---

```
               //   print_r($history_egrul);         
                                    if($history_fns) { var_dump($history_fns);   
                                        
                 ?>

                       <div class="egrul-content-tab <?=$fns_class?>" id="egrul-tab-content-1">
                      <div class="table">
                        <div class="table-body fns">

                            <?php      $t = 0; $hide = '';                  foreach ($history_fns as $key => $value) {
                                    $t++;    if($t>3) {$hide = ' style="display:none;"'; $show_button = 1;}

                                ?>
                          <div class="table-row" <?=$hide?>>
                              
                            <div class="title">
                              <h3><?=$key?></h3>
                            </div> 
                              <?php foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) { ?>
                            <div class="table-row-inner">
                              <div class="table-col date">
                                  <span><?=date("d.m.Y", strtotime($key1));?></span>
                              </div>
```

Comment: какая разница в каком порядке если ассоциативный массив

Comment: Вы, наверное, имеете в виду, что можно отсортировать, но тут какую функцию ни вставишь, массив не сортируется, а все значения просто пропадают "с фронта".. Пробовал с разными переменными и в разных участках кода, но, конечно с $history_fns в первую очередь.. Пробовал функции ksort(), arsort(), array_reverse(), sort()